# How to remove a part of a string prior to a symbol in PHP

Tags: php, html, math, numbers

This should be simple to answer, I'm just very new to this all...

If I have the following (the 89 is NOT constant — it could be 2, sometimes 3 numbers — but the /100 is):

> 89/100

how can I get just 89 saved as an integer?

Comment: Use preg_replace, or str_ireplace. What symbols are you talking about?

Comment: I don't think I understand. could you use `$item = explode('/', $myvar); echo $item[0];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Would explode on the `/`

```
explode('/','89/100');
```

then your result would be in the start of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
$num = intval($string);
```

This parses the string as an integer, and in this case, ignores everything from the "/" onwards.

To be clear, this will not include the "100".

```
intval("89/100") => 89
```

Here's a phpfiddle showing that it works: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n1b-reb

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, this won't include the 100.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest in theory, but it is not actually working. I'm just getting `1`.

Comment: @devirkahan, it should. See here a working example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n1b-reb

Comment: @BenLee Yes, I see that it's working. I think perhaps the number isn't saved as a string properly. Investigating...

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string up by the delimiter `/`, with **[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**.

```
$string = '89/100';

$data = explode('/', $string);

// 89
$number = (int)$data[0];
```